# Sessions by Page load time

Tags: google-analytics

putting together a report and I want to try to duplicate this report: https://www.soasta.com/blog/mobile-web-performance-monitoring-conversion-rate/. Trying to figure out how to do it in custom reporting in Google Analytics, but am having a difficult time coming up with the right format. the metrics i need are page load time and conversion rate, but when putting together a custom report i need to enter in a dimension too.... wondering if this is even possible given the way GA collects and stores data. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This is no possible with Google analytics, as it is not possible to use a measure (load time) as a dimension (in the X axis) inside custom reports or dashboards.

What you can do instead is download this data in a spreadsheet format, and create the chart in a spreadsheet.